# HttpClient not passing content during POST

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, httpclient

I'm doing a simple call using `HttpClient`. The problem is that it doesn't seem to send the content I provide. The server gives me an error for this and when I look at the request with Fiddler it doesn't show the content as it should:

```
HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
                new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> { 
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key1", "value1"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key2","value2"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key3","value3"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key4", "value4"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key5", "value5"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key6", "value6")
                });
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = "UTF-8";
HttpResponseMessage resposne = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("my_url"), content);
```

Any suggestions on what can be wrong?

Comment: What error does the server give? What does the request look like?

Comment: Your code seems fine. When you say that the content doesn't look like as it should could you explain how it should look like and how does it differ from the expected output?

Comment: Sorry for the noobish answer/personal question... but does changing to the following help?  'content.Headers.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";'

Comment: @Jammerz858, The `ContentType` property is not a string, so you cannot assign it to a string value. So this won't even compile.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Apologies, I was thinking of the HttpWebRequest objects 'ContentType' property - I was miles off!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that UserAgent is the issue.
[HttpClient on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn440594.aspx)

> By default, no user-agent header is sent with the HTTP request to the
>   web service by the HttpClient object. Some HTTP servers, including
>   some Microsoft web servers, require that a user-agent header be
>   included with the HTTP request sent from the client. The user-agent
>   header is used by the HTTP server to determine how to format some HTTP
>   pages so they render better on the client for different web browsers
>   and form factors (mobile phones, for example). Some HTTP servers
>   return an error if no user-agent header is present on the client
>   request. We need to add a user-agent header to avoid these errors
>   using classes in the Windows.Web.Http.Headers namespace. We add this
>   header to the HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders property.